Do you need to declare a purchase at customs if it is under the duty-free ceiling?
M. A brings back a watch he bought in the UK to France, by air, value £250, they hold the necessary receipts.
£250 is under the €430 ceiling for French customs
It's their only purchase, is declaration still needed though no duty would be owed?


... is declaration still needed though no duty would be owed?

No.

Goods you have purchased
or received as gifts in a third country*
When entering France, you may bring with you, in your
personal luggage*, goods purchased or received as gifts in a
third country* without filling out a declaration or paying duties
and taxes.
Depending on the case, the value of the said goods must not
exceed the amounts listed below: ...

From: https://franceintheus.org/IMG/pdf/trouble_free_travel_with_french_customs-2.pdf

do keep in mind that if your TOTAL exceeds the limit you need to declare EVERYTHING. So if you bring in 431 Euro in goods you need to declare everything making up that 431, if you bring in 429 you don't have to declare anything (unless some of those goods are in specific categories like raw agricultural products).

Did you paste the wrong URL by accident? The text you quote doesn’t appear anywhere on the page you’ve linked to.

@jwenting does that include items you intend to take back out (i.e. tourist/visitor, non-resident citizen bringing a gift or to sell), or items you had bought in EU and/or already paid duty for (i.e. resident)? I'd say close to 100% of international travelers violate this rule otherwise, as phones, laptops, smartwatches, etc all push things above this limit.

@ave depends. If you're bringing a clearly used (even if almost new) cellphone for personal use that's fully expected and normal, no need to declare it. If you're bringing 5 of them, still in their boxes and shrink wrapped, you need to declare them. Customs doesn't know about or care or trust your story that they're meant to take back home with you. Would you if you were them? Edge case would be items for personal use purchased in duty free at the departure airport. But there you'd have the receipts to prove that, and even then you can't go over legal limits for say alcohol or tobacco.

@jwenting my question was not "what's it like in practice", but "what's the legal cutoff".

@JanusBahsJacquet:  good catch. Corrected

In the case of entering France (or other EU countries), you are only obligated to declare items if you exceed the duty free limits.
There may of course be exceptions, but I would assume that this applies to most countries and not just the EU.

Which means that custom will only know if you have exceeded the duty free limit if you report it. It's like they want you to smuggle stuff in. /s

@PeterM No. They will find out that you are smuggling if you do not declare the item (usually an active decision by going through the green line at the customs checkpoint) and you are then picked out for a random check and they find more stuff in your luggage than what you are allowed to bring duty free.

What percentage of people get picked for a random inspection?  It is a number between 0% and 100%, but can't be either 100% or 0%.  So there is always a chance that you can slip something through.  Whether or not this is worth the risk is dependent on what you are smuggling and its value.

"random" check.

The moral hazard is addressed by the penalties for trying and failing to smuggle being more severe than the duty would have been had the goods simply been declared.  In the UK, for example, if you don't declare goods over your allowance, and are caught with them, the goods may simply be confiscated.  You may also be prosecuted.

My own anecdote: I once declared purchases well over 430 eur but didn't have to pay the tax because it was for my own use as souvenirs. This year there wasn't anyone at the station so I just walked out and home (easily over 600 eur in souvenirs).
Seems like as long as you're not buying 50 watches that are clearly ment to be sold they don't care.

@PeterM: What do you think customs should be doing instead?  Any policy short of “thoroughly search everybody” has the same problem.  Randomly checking a small percentage of entrants achieves a large fraction of the deterrence at a small fraction of the cost.

@PeterM Enough travellers are checked for it to work as a balanced deterrence. Searching all travellers would cost more than the authorities could cover with the higher tax revenues. It is perhaps worth to notice that when flying, checked luggage is often x-rayed by customs before you can pick it up to search for obvious contraband. Customs checks are often more thorough than what you see and notice.

hi @PeterM it's not really clear what you mean? Every single law, on Earth, is enforced in this way. Surely at times you have gotten away with speeding while driving, or even more serious crimes. Almost everyone has at one time or another taken something through customs, that, was above the official limit, without declaring it to the guys standing there waiting to randomly search people. So what? That's how every law on Earth works, no difference from say shoplifting upwards. (I would encourage you to NEVER TRY THIS unless you are very seasoned. In movies, the hero spy can act cool while he wa

lks a suitcase of diamonds through customs you know? If you actually try this in real life, you will sweat and they will instantly suss you out - it's what guards like that do all day all year and humans are incredibly bad at "pretending to be relaxed and innocent!")

@Tor-EinarJarnbjo Will they? How exactly do you suppose they will prove that the watch on your wrist, the laptop in your backpack or the gold necklace around you’re wearing was purchased during your stay abroad and not at home before you left? When it comes to items for personal use, even being pseudo-randomly selected for inspection, and the deterrence factor against non-declaration is extremely low.

@Tor-EinarJarnbjo if they do, the x-ray checks are probably also random. at least in the UK. I know people cough cough that have brought in via checked luggage plenty of non allowed goods without any issue at all. multiple times.

@JanusBahsJacquet They don't. If there is any doubt around the origin of goods you bring across the border, it is in most countries your problem to prove that no fees are due, not the customer officer's problem to prove the other way around. For valuable items, you are in many countries expected to declare them when travelling abroad to get a proof of temporary export you can use when coming back. Electronic products are often customized for different markets and the country of original sale can be determined. A laptop bought abroad will e.g. usually have a revealing keyboard layout.

@bracco23 Everyone knows of course someone who has brought too much across a border once, twice or many times without getting caught. At least everyone not living under a rock. I also know plenty of people having been caught, fined and had their stuff confiscated. So what?

Sure, for a laptop or a cell phone, there are ways to ascertain the original sell date. But they don’t normally do that unless they're already suspicious. I have been selected for a random check, and while they did ask me to unlock my phone and computer to show both were mine and in use, they didn’t ask for any proof of purchase or anything. (In most countries, the decision to fine is entirely at the discretion of customs officers, regardless of any evidence you present, so if they want to, they can fine you even if you show them proof of purchase in your own country from before you left. )

@PeterM anecdotally, sometimes in Turkey they pull all passengers over on a given day/hour/flight, asking them to put their bag(s) thru the x-ray. If they see anything that may be above the limit, they do a bag check, though that has never happened to me even when I was fairly close to the gift limit (and was carrying proof of them totaling <430eur for that reason). They also do a higher rate of random checks (pulling over seemingly random people) than in Germany (20% vs 0% IME).

@PeterM It's not random. There's many factors, as mentioned, x-raying checked baggage before pickup, behavioral profiling, looking at where you came from, observing how much luggage you have, sniffer dogs (cash, tobacco), and records: if you get caught once, prepare to be stopped frequently in the future.
